# Nuget Package cannot resolve dependencies. How to add all the dependent libraries into a single nuget package?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I have a project structure like this-
[image]

I have created a NuGet package with Project A but when I use this Nuget 'Project A.nupkg', I get an error - Cannot find dependencies 'Project C.dll'.

Project A.csproj is

```
    <PropertyGroup>               
        <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
            $(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);CopyProjectReferencesToPackage        
        </TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\ProjectB.csproj">
            <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
        </ProjectReference>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="CopyProjectReferencesToPackage" DependsOnTargets="BuildOnlySettings;ResolveReferences">
        <ItemGroup>
            <BuildOutputInPackage Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths- &gt;WithMetadataValue('ReferenceSourceTarget', 'ProjectReference'))-&gt;WithMetadataValue('PrivateAssets', 'All'))" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
```

Project B.csproj is

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Kinesis" version="3.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.SQS" version="3.0" />

        <ProjectReference Include="..\ProjectC.csproj">
            <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
        </ProjectReference>
    </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: You can use the `<file>` section directly, see my answer, it should be able to achieve your requiremens. :)

Comment: Hi Edward, any update of this question? :)

Comment: Hi Bowman Zhu-MSFT, this is not working for me. In project A bin\release\net6 folder, there is only A.dll and B.dll. 
C.dll is still missing because of which Nuget is also throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to achieve your requirements:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>test</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>BowmanZhu</authors>
    <owners>BowmanZhu</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>test</description>
    <releaseNotes>test</releaseNotes>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\net6.0\XxxApi.dll" target="lib\net6.0\XxxApi.dll" />
    <file src="bin\Debug\net6.0\YyyRepository.dll" target="lib\net6.0\YyyRepository.dll" />
    <file src="bin\Debug\net6.0\ZzzShared.dll" target="lib\net6.0\ZzzShared.dll" />
  </files>
</package>
```

After setting the dll path in `<files>`, you will be able to include all of the required dll file in a single nuget package:

[image]